# Analytic $N$th roots: can my statements here be generalized?

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm generally having trouble seeing when and why analytic functions have analytic $N$th roots.  I know the following statements to be true, but I know that they can also be generalized in various ways.  However, I'm not very confident in my ability to generalize them without making mistakes.

> 1 .  I know that if $g$ is analytic on a simply connected domain $V$, and $g(z) \neq 0$ on $V$, then there is an analytic function $\log$, defined on the image $g(V)$ (an open set), with the property that $e^{\log g} = g$.  For an arbitrary choice of $c \in V$, all we have to do is let $k$ be a complex number such that $e^k = g(c)$, and then define $\log g(z) = \int_c^z \frac{g'}{g} + k$. Then $g$ has an analytic $N$th root, namely $e^{\frac{1}{N} \log g}$.
>
> 2 .  More generally if $V$ is a disc $D_r(c)$, $g$ has a unique zero at $c \in V$, and the order of the zero is divisible by $N$, then $g$ also has an analytic $N$th root on $V$: write $g(z) = a_k(z-c)^k + \cdots$ with $k$ divisible by $N$, then $g(z) = (z-c)^k h(z)$, where $h(z)$ is analytic and nonvanishing on $D_r(c)$.  By (1), $h(z)$ has an analytic $N$th root on $D_r(c)$, and writing $(z-c)^k = ((z-c)^{\frac{k}{N}})^N$, we see that $g$ has an analytic $N$th root on $D_r(c)$.
>
> 3 .  If $g$ has a pole of order $k$ divisible by $N$ at $D_r(c)$, and $g$ doesn't vanish on $D_r(c) \setminus \{c\}$, then the same argument as in (2) works: $g$ has an analytic $N$th root on $D_r(c) \setminus \{c\}$, with a pole at $c$ of order $k/N$.

So, I would be very interested in anyone explaining, at a glance, how statements in (1), (2), (3) can be generalized.  In particular, I would be grateful if someone could answer the following questions:

> How many analytic $N$th roots are there of the function given in (1)?  Are there exactly $N$ of them?  How can they be defined?  What about those given in (2) and (3)?
>
> Can replace the disc $D_r(c)$ in (2) and (3) be replaced by an arbitrary domain?
>
> If $g$ is analytic on a domain $\Omega$ with various poles $c_i$ and zeroes $c_i'$, is there a necessary and sufficient condition for saying whether $g$ has an analytic $N$th root on $\Omega$?  If so, how many such functions are there?